# testcafe Command failed: "npm

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, automated-tests, testcafe

I installed testcafe globally and it was working with no issues, then I decided to install testcafe locally upon which it said it couldn't find npm in the node modules folder of my project. Then I installed npm locally and it started working again. After a while a decided to delete the local one and use the global but now that's broken and it keeps looking for the one in my local projects folder?!?! So if I then install npm in my local project again I get the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: "npm

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
```

Error when npm isn't installed in my local project:

```
ERROR Tested app failed with an error:

Error: Command failed: "npm
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: This information does not give me any clue as to why npm fails. How did you install it? What npm version are you using? What nodejs version are you using? What platform are you running it on?

Comment: Node v12.13.0 and npm 6.12.0. But as I said in my post it was working fine when I initially installed testcafe globally it was only after I installed it locally that I was unable to use the global version. Even after uninstalling and re-installing.

Comment: Try to completely reinstall Node.js using a Node installer ([https://nodejs.org/en/download/](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)).